# How to find out if a point is in a secified polygon in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, polygon

Suppose I have a multi-segment polygon. I defined the vertices like this in Matlab:

```
    X = [-1 -1 1 1;
         -4 -4 -3 -3];
    Y = [0 5 5 0;
        -6 -8 -8 -6]
```

And I can plot this multi-segment polygon like this:

```
patch(X',Y',[1 1 1 1;1 1 1 1]')
```

And here is the look of it:
[image: A multi-segment polygon]

How Can I find out if a particular point is in the regions defined by my polygons?
Please notice that I want to lump these two shapes together and treat them the same in this matter
I can do it with one polygon with this code, but it doesn't work for more:

```
inpolygon(A(1),A(2), X(1,:),Y(1,:))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`inpolygon`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html) can handle this situation, but the separate polygon vertices need to be [separated with a `NaN`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html?expandall=true#buanygl-3) such that no connection is made.

This test case gives me expected results:

```
 X = [-1 -1  1  1 ;
      -4 -4 -3 -3];
 Y = [ 0  5  5  0 ;
      -6 -8 -8 -6];

X = [X';nan(1,size(X,1))];
Y = [Y';nan(1,size(Y,1))];

isIn = inpolygon([-3.5,-2,0],[-7,-4,2],X(:),Y(:))
```

which outputs

```
isIn =
     1     0     1
```

Comment: How can I patch (plot) X and Y now?

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator To use patch(), I would just assign the modified values of `X` and `Y` to different variables.  I was lazy in the example.